# Progress Bar to run during parse

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, progress-bar

I would like to be able to run a progress bar while my parse_files function is running. I have written both functions but how can i get the progress bar to actually show the progress of the parse_files function?

**Parse Code:**

```
def parse_files(directory):
    results = []
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith(('.cfg', '.startup', '.confg')):
            file_name = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            with open(file_name, "r") as in_file:
                for line in in_file:
                    match = re.search('^hostname\s(\S+)$', line)
                    if match:
                        results.append(match.group(1))
    return results
```

**Progress Bar Code:**

```
def progress_bar():
    from time import sleep
    for i in range(21):
        sys.stdout.write('\r')
        sys.stdout.write("[%-20s] %d%%" % ('='*i, 5*i))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sleep(0.25)
```

Based on the comments below for the tqdm i have it working the way i want. However like i said i'm trying to avoid additional modules, however, this should be ok.

```
def parse_files(directory):
    results = []
    for i in tqdm(range(1000)):
        time.sleep(.01)
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith(('.cfg', '.startup', '.confg')):
            file_name = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            with open(file_name, "r") as in_file:
                for line in in_file:
                    match = re.search('^hostname\s(\S+)$', line)
                    if match:
                        results.append(match.group(1))
    return results
```

Comment: draw progess inside function `parse_files()` - without `for`-loop and without `sleep()`. Now you will have to run two separated `threads`

Comment: Actually, that project now lives at https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm

Comment: I will look into that Gustavio but i want to avoid importing extra modules.
Furas - I think i know what you said but i'm fairly new to programming so i'm not 100% on that.

Comment: So it looks like linux does not like the ascii. How do i format this so linux will like it? I've read a post that says to do reload(sys) sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8') but when i do that the progress bar does not have the # symbol and it scolls down the page as it progresses rather than a nice clean bar.